# query about $ in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-function

how to write query for
 " $500 + $600 = $1100 "

Comment: what exactly do you want ? what Tables do you have and what result should be returned?

Comment: Have you tried:  `select concat('$', 500 + 600)`.

Comment: tysm @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT '$'+CAST(600+500 AS CHAR)
```